# upload image with Multer not from Form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I have an image URL in my code and i want to save it as a FormData with multer.

i tried 2 ways for save image with multer.

number1 perfectly works but number2 dosent work. i think the problem is in the *"part 2"*

***number 1 (works)***

my function to save image from form

```
 const onChangeUploadImage = (e) => {
    //-----------------------------------------------part 1---------------
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    uploadTheImage(formData); 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  };
```

the form

```
<Form.Group>
   <Form.Label>upload your image</Form.Label>
   <Form.Control type='text' onChange={(e) => {console.log(e.target.value);}}/>
   <Form.File
      id='image-file'
      label='choose file'
      custom
      onChange={onChangeUploadImage}
    ></Form.File>
</Form.Group>
```

***number 2 (dosent work)***

my function to save stage

```
const handleSaveStage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dataURL = stageRef.current.toDataURL({
      mimeType: 'image/png',
      quality: 0,
      pixelRatio: 2,
    });
    //dataURL is correct image of stage. i checked it.
    //-----------------------------------------------part 2---------------
    var file = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    uploadTheImage(formData);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  };
```

the stage

```
<div ref={stageRef}>
  ...
</div>;
<Button onClick={handleSaveImage}>Save Stage</Button>
```

in the second way i got
"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" and
"POST localhost:3000/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)" in console

***other codes***

a function for convert URI to Blob ([refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/10315704))

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding some code that i find from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801256/10315704)

```
const handleSaveStage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dataURL = stageRef.current.toDataURL({
      mimeType: 'image/png',
      quality: 0,
      pixelRatio: 2,
    });
    //dataURL is correct image of stage. i checked it.
    //-----------------------------------------------part 2---------------
    var f = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
    const file = new File([f], 'capture.png', {
      type: 'image/png',
    });
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    uploadTheImage(formData);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  };
```